# How to pass a ModelResult class from lmfit in a multiprocess shared array?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, lmfit

I have some issues using **lmfit** in different process to make my code faster. How can I define some share array that contains the results of every fitting?

I have a cube of data, with position a, b, x and f(x). I made a model in **lmfit** that work nice and adjust f(x) for one point, returning some parameters. Lmfit returns a class called *ModelResult()* witch contains every of these parameters and some extra data useful. So, I need run this fitting for each a and b, and later make a cube with this parameters and maybe the extra data. I can run this in a linear way (without parallelize) but I have more than 1000 points and the model is complicated, so it take more than a 15000 seconds.

My problem start when I use the **multiprocessing** lib. I need to share data between every process so when a process finish, lock the variable and store the results inside, and later unlock the variable. The multiprocessing lib has *Value()* or *Array()* to do what I need. I intented to use Array, and made some change of variable to pass from a and b to c where c is the range of a*b. But I can't define an Array to keep the *ModelResult()* for each c.

Here the code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time 
from lmfit import Model
from numpy import sqrt, exp, pi

#Set time zero
start_time = time.time()

#Example of functions to fit
def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    """1-d gaussian: gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)"""
    return (amp / (sqrt(2*pi) * wid)) * exp(-(x-cen)**2 / (2*wid**2))

def linear(x, slope, intercept):
    """a linear function"""
    return slope*x + intercept

#Function to fit every point
def fit_point(a,b,data_cube,x,pars,mod):
        pos=int(b+(a*10))
        data_point = np.array(data_cube[:,a,b])
        #print(pos,mp.current_process().name)
        error_point= np.array((data_point*0)+0.002) #Example error
        res_point=mod.fit(data_point, pars, weights=1./error_point, x=x)
        print(res_point.fit_report())
        cube_res[pos]=res_point
        return #cube_res[:]

#Invented some data
x=np.arange(10)
data_cube=np.random.rand(10, 10, 10)

#Example of a model with 2 gaussians and a line
mod = Model(linear, prefix='l_')+Model(gaussian, prefix='g1_')+Model(gaussian, prefix='g2_')
pars= mod.make_params()
pars['g1_amp'].set(0.5)
pars['g2_amp'].set(0.5)
pars['g1_cen'].set(2)
pars['g2_cen'].set(3)
pars['g1_wid'].set(0.5)
pars['g2_wid'].set(0.5)
pars['l_slope'].set(1)
pars['l_intercept'].set(1)

#Definition of the shared Array #Where I think there is the problem!
cube_res = mp.Array('u', 100)

#Definition of the process and starts
processes = []
for a in np.arange(0,10):
    for b in np.arange(0,10):
        process = mp.Process(target=fit_point, args=(a,b,data_cube,x,pars,mod))
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
for process in processes:
    process.join()

print('Time count')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))    

#Intent to print some results
#print(cube_res[20].fit_report)

#Final, to recover a,b
#final_cube_res = np.reshape(cube_res, (100,100))
```

The errors are:

```
TypeError: unicode string expected instead of ModelResult instance
```

This is because I define *mp.Array('u', 100)*, where 'u' is unicode and 100 is the range.

I don't know how to define the Array to can save the ModelResult inside.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you cannot put a `lmfit.ModelResult` into a string.  In fact, your

```
cube_res = mp.Array('u', 100)
```

is saying that `cube_res` is an Array of 100 unicode characters. That is, each result would need to be 1 character long. I think what you want instead is to use a `multiprocessing.Manger().dict` to hold the results.

```
cube_res = mp.Manager().dict()
```

This will allow you to use the (x, y) position as the key and you can then put the ModelResult as the value....

... but: you won't be able to save the `ModelResult` directly because the data shared between multiprocesses needs to be pickled, and in general complex objects, especially those with methods, are not easily picklable.  The good news is that `lmfit.ModelResult` has a `dumps()` method that you can use to convert that object into a picklable json string.   So then your code would use

```
    res_point=mod.fit(data_point, pars, weights=1./error_point, x=x)
    print(res_point.fit_report())
    cube_res[(a,b)] = res_point.dumps()
    return
```

in your `fit_point()` function.

We're not done yet, because restoring the `ModelResult` from the dumped json string is slightly complicated (lmfit has helper functions for this, but these assume you've written the results to a file). You would have to do this after you've `joined` all your processes:

```
print('Time count')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

import lmfit
# make a dummy ModelResult -- we'll overwrite everything for this
modres = lmfit.model.ModelResult(lmfit.Model(gaussian), lmfit.Parameters())

# make a dictionary of the functions you actually used (the function *names* 
# are included in the dumped string, but not the functions themselves)
funcdefs = {'gaussian': gaussian, 'linear': linear}
for pos, dumpval in cube_res.items():
    modelresult = modres.loads(dumpval, funcdefs=funcdefs)
    print('### Result for fit ', pos)
    print(modelresult.fit_report())
```

I think that should get you started...